# Is the a cleaner way to fetch the top value in an array of arrays?

Tags: .net, arrays, powershell, coding-style

I've got an array of arrays that are of radically different sizes, but all integers.  What I need to do is find the top value of each one to compare against something later.  Not too hard, but when I write it out, the code feels almost unreadable at first glance.  Specifically this line:

```
$logScaleList[$i][$logScaleList[$i].Length-1]
```

As this obtuse, or is it just the fact that when dealing with 2d arrays, you're going to have ugly nested statements?

Full code here:

```
$logScaleList = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@() 

[void]$logScaleList.Add(@(100,126,158,200,251,316,398,501,631,794,1000,1259,1585,1995,2512,3162,3981,5012,5230))
[void]$logScaleList.Add(@(100,126,158,200,251,316,398,501,631,794,1000,1259,1585,1995,2512,3162,3981,5012,5850))
[void]$logScaleList.Add(@(1000,1259,1585,1995,2512,3162,3981,3162,5012,6310,7390))
[void]$logScaleList.Add(@(1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,13,16,20,25,32,40,50,63,79,100,126,158,200,251,316,398,501,631,794,1000,1259,1585,1995,2512,3162,3981,5012))
[void]$logScaleList.Add(@(1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,13,16,20,25,40,50,63,79,100,126,158,200,251,316,398,501,631,794,1000,1259,1585,1995,2512))


for ($i = 0; $i -lt $logScaleList.count; $i++)
{ 
    write-host "Top value is" $logScaleList[$i][$logScaleList[$i].Length-1] 

}
```

Comment: Top as in highest value? Or as in array element 0?

Comment: Um, `$LogScaleList | ForEach{$_ | Select -Last 1}` or `$LogScaleList | ForEach{$_[-1]}`, either of those will get you the last value of the nested array. If the array is not in order you pipe to `Sort` and then to `Select -Last 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ForEach-Object` or a `foreach` loop to avoid the first index operator:

```
foreach($List in $LogScaleList){
    $List[$List.Length - 1]
}
```

You can reference the last item by index `-1`, avoiding the `Length` property as well (if that seems less ugly to you):

```
foreach($List in $LogScaleList){
    $List[-1]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sort](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113403) cmdlet to sort the array and select the first item:

```
$logScaleList | % { $_ | sort -Descending | select -first 1 }
```

Output:

```
5230
5850
7390
5012
2512
```